# Vuejs dispatch data from child to parent without placing it into an array

Tags: parent-child, vue.js

I'm trying to take data that is dispatched from a child component and pass it into a parent component but so far I've only been able to find an example of this being pushed into an array.

In the child I have a method set up like this

```
  methods: { 
   savePost: function() {
     this.$dispatch('child-data', this.childData)
     this.childData = ''
   }
  }
```

And the parent is set to grab it and place it in an array

```
data: {
 childSelect: [],
}
events: {
 'child-data' : function (childData) {
  this.childSelect.push(childData)
}
```

So I know that this is just going to push the childs data into an array but I'm looking for a way to set `data:{ childSelect: ''}` and have dispatched data from the event replace `childSelect` each time it's updated.

I've seen examples in the documentation but I'm still new to this so I'm not entirely sure how to adjust what I've found to fit this child -> parent interaction.

I hope this makes sense -_- !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're after. Maybe something like this?

```
events: {
    'child-data' : function (childData) {
        this.childSelect = childData;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was it! For some reason I convinced myself it was much more complicated, didn't take a step back. Thanks!

Comment: If you're doing stuff like this on a regular basis, you may want to look into Vuex.  It makes sharing data between components much simpler.

Comment: Using Vuex for the first time on this project. For this specific issue though the data is changing in the child component based on a radio selection and then being passed to the parent (user selects an option, option selection data is shared with the parent component that displays it as text), so I'm not really sure if there's some way I can set this up using vuex.